# Redirect to Created Post after Create Post Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga

I have a blog where you can create a post, that works fine. What I want to do is redirect to the newly created post after creation.

`postActions.js:`

```
export function* watchCreatePost() {
  yield takeEvery(CREATE_POST, createPostSaga);
}

function* createPostSaga(action) {
  const token = yield select(selectToken);
  const headerParams = {
    Authorization: `JWT ${token}`
  };
  const apiCall = () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", action.payload.title);
    formData.append("content", action.payload.content);
    formData.append("thumbnail", action.payload.thumbnail);
    formData.append("tags", action.payload.tags);
    formData.append("slug", generateSlug(action.payload.title));
    return axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/posts/",
      data: formData,
      headers: headerParams
    })
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  };

  try {
    const response = yield call(apiCall);
    const post = {};
    post[response.id] = { ...response };
    yield put({ type: ADD_POST, payload: response });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Like I said this creates the post fine, but I am unsure on how to redirect after it completes. I know in `redux-thunk` you can use `.then()` but not an option as far as I can tell with `redux-saga`.

Comment: Is the newly created post on another URL? If so, `this.props.history.push(URL_OF_BLOG_POST)`. Or if the new blog post is on the same page but you just want to scroll the page to it, then `ReactDom.findDOMNode(DOM_NODE).scrollIntoView()`.

Comment: I could use `this.props.history.push(URL_OF_BLOG_POST)` if I knew the url of the post, but I don't until the saga finishes.

Comment: After `yield put({ type: ADD_POST, payload: response })` add `yield call(redirectToBlogPost)` ?

Comment: That would work... if I knew how to `redirectToBlogPost`. `props.history` is not available in the saga, and I have no way of knowing the URL until the saga completes, so I can't redirect from the component because I don't know the URL, and I can't redirect from the saga because it doesn't have a method of redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ADD_POST` action probably will be managed by a reducer that updates a sort of `posts` array into the state I guess?

If so
- add a `phantom` component with a `render` function that returns `null`
- add the `state.posts` array to its state props
- as soon the `state.posts` is updated you can redirect the user because since it's a component you have access to the history

If you use `React-router` or a similar library you can import the `navigate` function and redirect the user inside a saga too

Let me know